# fancyhdr: Section number, Section, colon and subsection in header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am a bit confused with the `fancyhdr` options. I currently have this style for my headers:
MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}%use oneside to ensure no blanks\
\usepackage[text={5.45in,8.5in}, left=1.5in, right=1.25in, top=1.25in, bottom=1.25in, headheight=15.91pt, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[table,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace, fancyhdr, amsmath, amssymb,amsthm, graphicx, color, lscape, longtable, booktabs, caption, wrapfig, hyperref, pdfpages, capt-of, microtype, lmodern, titlesec, tikz, lipsum}


% Ensures we put the section name/number on the left side and page number on right

\fancyhf{}                % clear all header and footer fields
\pagestyle{fancy}           %define page style
\pagenumbering{roman}       %page numbering style: before main text
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt} % make space for the rule
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{} % get rid of headers on plain pages
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % and the line
}
\doublespacing

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Some chapter}
\section{Section I}
\lipsum[1-1]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Section II}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Subsection One}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Subsection Two}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
\section{Section III}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Subsection for this section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Another subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]
```

The current header looks like this:

### 1.1 Section I

This is fine for most of my sections. However for some sections, say section II in the above MWE, I would like the header to read like so:

### 1.2 Section II: Subsection Two

I would then like the header to switch back to the current style in the next section (Section III):

### 1.3 Section III

I read several posts here on fancyhdr and [the section on fancyhdr in wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Customising_with_fancyhdr) but I am having some trouble getting it to work, especially with the colon in between. Any help would be awesome!

PS: If this is a duplicate question, could you please point me to the relevant question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum,setspace}

\pagestyle{fancy}           %define page style
\fancyhf{}                  % clear all header and footer fields

\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{%
  \ifsubsectioninheader
    \def\subsectiontitle{: #1}%
  \else
    \def\subsectiontitle{}%
  \fi}
\newif\ifsubsectioninheader
\def\subsectiontitle{}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\rightmark\ifsubsectioninheader\subsectiontitle\fi}}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt} % make space for the rule
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{} % get rid of headers on plain pages
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % and the line
}
\doublespacing

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}


\begin{document}
% \frontmatter %%% use this for roman page numbering

\mainmatter %%% use this for switching to arabic page numbering

\chapter{Some chapter}

\section{Section I}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Section II}
\subsectioninheadertrue

\lipsum[1-2]

\subsection{Subsection One}
\lipsum[1-2]

\subsection{Subsection Two}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsectioninheaderfalse


\section{Section III}
\lipsum[1-2]

\subsection{Subsection for this section}
\lipsum[1-2]

\subsection{Another subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

We redefine `\subsectionmark` to keep the title, but only when the conditional `\ifsubsectioninheader` is true; in this case the header will show the information. The usual definition of `\subsectionmark` is to do nothing.

As an aside, notice the better method the `book` class has for switching from roman page numbering to arabic. With `\frontmatter` you have also other advantages: the chapters there are not numbered, but go automatically in the table of contents.

Comment: thank you so much for this very cool way to do it! It helps me a bit more with understanding how `fancyhdr` works. Thanks also for that nifty book class `\frontmatter` trick! I am going to try it out on my dissertation.

Comment: I just noticed a slight problem with this solution. I’m using the `\subsectioninheadertrue` and `\subsectioninheaderfalse` to redefine the header multiple times in my document. It works fine the first time. However, when I use it for the 2nd time, my section headers are appearing a page earlier than they should. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: @Ariel Does it happen *always*?

Comment: Thank you for asking that! I did some more checks and the problem only appears in one condition - when the section (where I want the header to show the subsection) starts at the top of a page.

Comment: @Ariel Put a `\pagebreak` command just before that `\section` command. Do this check when the document is in final form, so as not to spoil it during revisions. The problem is that the `\section` command is read *before* the page break decision is made; with `\pagebreak` this won't happen.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you! In this chapter I am working on, every subsection starts on a new page. I had to put a `\pagebreak` before next subsection as well to prevent the subsection titles from displaying on the previous page's header.

Comment: Congratulations on 500k, egreg :) An astonishing achievement, thanks for everything you do for us on the site :)